# Let $G$ be a group such that $a^2=e$ for all $a \in G$. Show that $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\cdots\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ ($n$ factors).

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

I aim to show the following fact: **Let $G$ be a group such that $a^2=e$ for all $a \in G$. Show that $|G|=2^n$ and $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\cdots\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ ($n$ factors).**

I can prove that G is a $p$-group, with  $|G|=2^n$. What theorem or fact could guarantee that isomorphism?

Comment: Perhaps useful: $ba=ba(e)=ba(ab)^2=b(aa)bab=(bb)ab=ab$, so $G$ is necessarily abelian.

Comment: Unless the group is *finite* the claim may be false as the number of factors could not be finite...

Comment: @πr8 yes, good! I tried to write G as the product of normal subgroups with order 2. But, apparently, this is not the right way.

Comment: You can use the fundamental theorem of abelian groups, or you could notice that your group is a vector space over the field with two elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@πr8 has shown $G$ is Abelian.
You are given $|G|$ is finite, so $G$ is finitely generated.  Therefore, $G$ is a finitely generated Abelian group, about which there is a big theorem.  (It is related to the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Modules over a PID.)  Finally, I observe that $2$ is in the annihilator of the $\Bbb{Z}$-module $G$, which with the big theorem, leaves no options for the factor structure of $G$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: show that $G$ is abelian and has structure of a vector space over $\mathbb Z_2$.